# model class not found error in laravel 4 in

Tags: php, laravel

I create a model under `models/admin/users.php`, now i accessing model in controller to get data from data base using `$userList = Users::all()` but it generate error

```
Class admin\Users not found
```

Comment: Try to run `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: users.php is lower case, don't know if that's a type here or in your actual code ?

Comment: i tried that but it not worked for me @Maraboc

Comment: please check if your models/admin/users.php have correct namespace: `namespace models\admin;` and the class have correct name: `class user ...`